# Delphi Datasnap send ClientDataSet to Server using tcp/ip

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, datasnap, tclientdataset

I have a simple DataSnap TCP/IP based client server application. I created 
a ClientDataSet on Client Application and filled it some data. Now how can I send my ClientDataSet records to Server so that I  can process it and eventually save some data to server.

### Edited

So I tried the below code, but the problem is that at server I am getting  1 less record than what I am sending from client

### Client Code

```
var
 cd: TClientDataSet;
begin
  cd:= TClientDataSet.Create(self);
  cd.Data := cdsCustomer.Data;
Memo1.Lines.Add(IntTostr( cd.RecordCount )) ;
 ServerMethods1Client.TestDataSet( CD);
```

### Server Code

```
function TServerMethods1.TestDataSet(ds: tdataset): string; 
begin     
  try
    DataSetProviderCommon.DataSet := ds;
    if not DataSetProviderCommon.DataSet.eof then
     TempClientDataSet.Open;

    if  TempClientDataSet.RecordCount >0 then      
       Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add( IntTostr( TempClientDataSet.RecordCount) )       
    else
        Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add( ' Not records found' ) ;

    DataSetProviderCommon.DataSet.Close;   
  except on e: Exception do
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('TestDataSet error :' + e.Message )   ;   
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass the Data property to the server as OleVariant type (likewise you can pass data from server back to the client using OleVariant result type or var/out parameters):

**Client Code**

```
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add( IntTostr( cdsCustomer.RecordCount ) );
  ServerMethods1Client.TestDataSet( cdsCustomer.Data );
end;
```

**Server Code**

```
function TServerMethods1.TestDataSet(ds: OleVariant): string; 
begin     
  try
    TempClientDataSet.Data := ds;

    if TempClientDataSet.RecordCount > 0 then      
      Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add( IntTostr( TempClientDataSet.RecordCount ) )       
    else
      Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add( 'No records found' ) ;

    TempClientDataSet.Close;   
  except on e: Exception do
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add( 'TestDataSet error: ' + e.Message );   
  end;
end;
```